# how to use variable names in karate-config.js?

Tags: automation, cucumber, karate

how to use variable names in karate-config.js?

in my karate-config.js

```
function preConfiguration() {
  var env = karate.env;
  if (!env) { env = 'prod'; }  // default when karate.env not set

  var config = {
          env: env,
            Url : 'http://localhost:8443/one',
      };
  if (env == 'prod') {

          config.Url = 'http://localhost:8443/one';
          config.dbUrl = 'jdbc:oracle://10.10.10.10:5443/abcd';
          config.dbUserName = 'abc';
          config.dbPassword = 'abc123';
      


  }
  else if (env == 'test') { //production environment settings
          config.Url = '';
  }
    return config;
```

My requirement is to put url ( **'http://localhost:8443/one';**), dburl(**'jdbc:oracle://10.10.10.10:5443/abcd';**), dbusername(**'abc';**), dbpassword (**'abc123';**) in variables (in karate-config.js) in karate framework. Could any one help me out please?

Comment: this is so basic I'll let someone else here answer

Comment: @Peter Thomas 
I was trying this..
config.Url = $(URL) and 
config.dbUserName = $(dbUserName )
is this correct ?

Comment: nope, have you read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configuration

Comment: in the doc also its same
  var config = { // base config JSON
    appId: 'my.app.id',
    appSecret: 'my.secret',
    someUrlBase: 'https://some-host.com/v1/auth/',
    anotherUrlBase: 'https://another-host.com/v1/'

Comment: Got it 
config.Url = $URL